# Enable touchpad

Tags: touchpad

Some time ago I disabled the touchpad. Now, I would like to enable it
again, but unfortunately I do not know how I disabled it back then. Here is
what I tried to enable it again:

With xinput:

```
$ xinput list | grep Touchpad
⎜   ↳ ELAN0501:00 04F3:3037 Touchpad            id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]

$ xinput --enable 13
```

With synclient:

```
$ synclient TouchpadOff=0
```

Check with dconf:

```
$ dconf read /org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/touchpad/send-events
'enabled'
```

Neither worked so far. And there are no settings in the BIOS to enable/disable the touchpad.

What other alternatives exist to disable/enable the touchpad?

**Update:**

```
$ xinput list-props 13

Device 'ELAN0501:00 04F3:3037 Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (143):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (145): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (275): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (276):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (277):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (278):    12.500000
    Synaptics Edges (297):  129, 3105, 126, 2211
    Synaptics Finger (298): 25, 30, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (299):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (300):   175
    Synaptics Tap Durations (301):  180, 180, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (302):   1
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (303):  0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (304):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (305):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (306): 79, 79
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (307): 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (308):   1, 1
    Synaptics Move Speed (309): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.050125, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (310):    0
    Synaptics Locked Drags (311):   0
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (312):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (313): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2
    Synaptics Click Action (314):   1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (315): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (316):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (317): 0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (318):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (319): 0
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (320):    10, 200
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (321): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (322):    30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (323): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Resolution Detect (324):  1
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (325):  0
    Synaptics Gestures (326):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (327):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (328): 32, 32
    Synaptics Area (329):   0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Soft Button Areas (330):  1617, 0, 1916, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (331): 19, 19
    Device Product ID (268):    1267, 12343
    Device Node (267):  "/dev/input/event11"
```

```
$ lsb_release -a

LSB Version:    core-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:printing-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:security-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Comment: What does `xinput list-props 13` show? Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: @Pilot6 I've updated the post.

Comment: It is enabled. Install `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-18.04` and install `xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-18.04`. This is in case you have HWE stack.

Comment: @Pilot6 I'm not using HWE kernels on this system.

Comment: It is not about kernel, but about `xserver-xorg` package. If you have it without `hwe`, then install `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` and remove `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`.

Comment: @Pilot6 These non-hwe packages are already installed.

Comment: Remove the `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`

Comment: This would remove lubuntu-core and other lubuntu-* packages, too.

Comment: This is the first time Lubuntu was mentioned.